# Pymongo external harddrive to store collection

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, external

I googled quite a bit for this but could not find anything on this:

I am using mongodb/Pymongo on my local machine. Now I want to create a collection which is too big for my internal hard drive.

Is there a way to indicate MongoDB that I want to store a specific collection to a different path or would I have to move the entire database to the external hard-drive?

Any comments would be welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no straightforward way to save a single collection's data in a different location.

There are a limited number of ways that you *can* keep different data in different places, but none of them are granular enough to work on different collections:

1. The [storage.directoryPerDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.directoryPerDB) config option allows you to keep each *database* in a different directory - but that would still keep all collection data in the same folder.
2. The [storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.directoryForIndexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.directoryForIndexes) option allows you to keep index data in a separate directory from the collection data - but that would still keep all collection data in the same folder.

In both of these cases, and also for the journal, it is possible to [use a symbolic link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56339/22442) to a folder on a different drive - but this is not possible for a single collection's data.

The standard solution for splitting a single very large collection's data across different locations is by [sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/); but that requires multiple different servers, each with its own MongoDB installation. In your case, running just on a local machine, I don't think sharding would help you much; a better solution is probably just to buy a much bigger hard drive.